# Объясните мне пожалуйста

Tags: веб-программирование, запрос

Зачем это

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Думаю, если вы загуглите каждый из этих meta-тегов, то без труда найдёте ответы самостоятельно

Comment: думаю данный вопрос елементарно гуглиться и не стоило его задавать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Атрибут `charset` необходим для установки кодировки документа. На данный момент стандартом является кодировка `utf-8`

> `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Это для дополнения для браузера Chrome Frame от Google, он может быть установлен на разные версии IE. По сути запускает хром внутри IE. Метатег `X-UA-Compatible` позволяет выбирать, в какой версии Internet Explorer должна отображаться страница.

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

`viewport` - это то, что видит пользователь без прокрутки окна. Почитать про атрибуты `viewport` можно вот [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Viewport#%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0_viewport)

Comment: > Это для дополнения для браузера Chrome Frame от Google — это неправда и никакой хром тут и рядом не стоял https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-iedoco/380e2488-f5eb-4457-a07a-0cb1b6e4b4b5

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, не знал. задавался этим вопросом и находил такой ответ как у меня, вот я его и написал, что помнил.

Comment: @AlexeyTen отредактируйте мой ответ как считаете нужным